# using jquery with vb.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

is some one try to use jquery with vb.net, like

```
if InvalidUser() then show ModalDialog 
or if CreateNewUserForm.Confirm()=true then do some thing...
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you want to execute a javascript function. If so use [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)

```
public static void RegisterStartupScript(
    Control control,
    Type type,
    string key,
    string script,
    bool addScriptTags
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you truly understand what it is you're asking. jQuery (or Javascript) is a **client-side** technology that executes in the **browser**. ASP.NET (using VB.NET or C#) is a **server-side** language that executes on the **server**.

You cannot combine the two as in your example given that they execute on physically different machines.

Now, there are numerous ways to handle communication between the two components of your application, such as the example given by [BrunoLM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856181/using-jquery-with-vb-net/5856220#5856220), but you'd have to be more specific to get a concrete answer.

Comment: And before anyone whines about it, yes I know Javascript can execute on the server.